# Trouble with fetch error handling in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch

I'm learning how to use fetch and was trying the following syntax:

```
const [stuff, setStuff] = useState([]);
const request = "link-to-API";

const data = await fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return {} //(or [], or an empty return, or any return at all)
    })

setStuff(data.hits)
```

Then, in the return, I have:

```
{stuff.map((element) => (
        <Thing
          title={element.label}
          link={element.url}
        />
      ))}
```

Thinking I could just render an empty object whenever my fetch fails. Except, this works only when the fetch itself works. React gives me the error

> "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: Failed to
> fetch)."

But I can't find any solution online. How could I handle the errors just by not rendering anything?
(that's not the only part I'm rendering, I just want to render an empty div, not conditionally render that part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `await` you can't use `then` and `catch` methods

It's important that you use `await` in `async` function

```
let data = null
try{
    const response = await fetch(request)
    data = response.json();
} catch(err)  {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: since, its a functional component, you cannot have a random retrun statement returning nothing. the return will result in "Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Answer (score 0):

you can try removing the await keyword, as  you are using .then
also the datafetching part should be included inside useEffect

```
const [stuff, setStuff] = useState([]);
const request = "link-to-API";
    
useEffect( ()=> {
    fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setStuff(data.hits))
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
},[])
```

Comment: Not returning anything gives the same problem, I'll edit the question